# Using flexbox on a table row?

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I can't find any quick answers to this. Is it cool to use `display: flex;` on a table row (`<tr>`) element?

It feels wrong. But if there's no compatibility issues I will do it

[Here's a codepen of what I'm talking about](https://codepen.io/connorv/pen/boEYOB?editors=1100)

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked,
input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label,
input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #666;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label:before,
input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label:after,
input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #fc8f3f;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.dots-wrap form {
  width: 700px;
}

.dots-wrap div {
  width: 900px;
}

.dots-wrap form,
.dots-wrap div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dots-wrap div label {
  font-size: 11px;
}

h2.strikethrough {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 700px;
}

h2.strikethrough:before {
  border-top: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* this centers the line to the full width specified */
  position: absolute;
  /* positioning must be absolute here, and relative positioning must be applied to the parent */
  top: 32px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 95%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.dots-wrap form div h2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dots-wrap form div {
  width: 100%;
}

.dots-wrap form div h2 p {
  margin: 0px;
}


/*dasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf*/
```

```html
<div class="dots-wrap">
  <form action="#">
    <div>
      <h2 class="strikethrough">
        <p>
          <a href="#tab-t1">
            <input type="radio" id="test1" name="radio-group" checked>

            <label for="test1"></label>
          </a>
        </p>
        <p>
          <a href="#tab-t2">
            <input type="radio" id="test2" name="radio-group">
            <label for="test2"></label>
          </a>
        </p>
        <p>
          <a href="#tab-t3">
            <input type="radio" id="test3" name="radio-group">
            <label for="test3"></label>
          </a>
        </p>
        <p>
          <a href="#tab-t4">
            <input type="radio" id="test3" name="radio-group">
            <label for="test4"></label>
          </a>
        </p>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div>
    <div>
      <label for="test1">Marketing & Lead Generation</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="test2">Underwriting</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="test3">Customer Management</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="test4">Fraud, Collections & Recoveries</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using tables instead of divs?

Comment: it's for the line that connects the dots for the effect in my codepen

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In terms of compatibility issues, you'll just have to test how different browsers render flex properties applied to table elements. I don't see any problems in Chrome.

In terms of best practices, I don't see any problems, either. HTML table elements exist for their semantic value. The CSS applied to these elements has no semantic value. Therefore, switching a table-row (`tr`) from its default `display: table-row` to `display: flex`, doesn't alter the semantics, just the layout.

However, I think you're venturing into unchartered territory. You're mixing the oldest HTML with the newest CSS. Because browsers have long-standing algorithms for rendering tables, I wouldn't mix them with flex properties. I would expect a conflict to mess things up. I would use divs instead.

Comment: switched these to divs and stopped worrying about this problem altogether.

Comment: LOL! Yeah, I always try to keep things as simple as possible. Flex and table elements are not worth the time, effort, hassle or risk IMO.

Comment: div won't copy correctly to spreadsheet and etc

Answer (score 1):

There would be compatibility issues between MS IE/Edge and other browsers. Edge still implements older version of Flexbox spec, according to which table cells inside the flex container should be wrapped with an anonymous table box, and this anonymous table becomes the only flex element. According to the newer spec, each table cell becomes the individual flex item. Chrome always behaved this way (in fact, the spec was changed to match reality better), and Firefox changed its behavior at some point and now it behaves the same way as Chrome.

Also, by making the table row the flex container you destroy one of the biggest advantages of the table structure — the 2D structure of rows and columns. Since cells don't belong to the table context anymore, they wouldn't align into columns, unless you set them the same widths manually. (This might be irrelevant in this particular case, but relevant in general case of applying Flexbox styles to the table elements).

That said, this hack can be useful in a very limited set of situations for making tables responsive for a narrow screen (using `flex-wrap:wrap`). But usually I'd avoid it.

Comment: you're right - this isn't a great use case for tables at all.