# How to centre this html in an email?

Tags: html, email

I'm struggling with the html in this email (for a booking management tool called `[https://www.checkfront.com/][1]`).

This code works fine sent from gmail to gmail, Office to gmail, pagebuilder to gmail, etc. When sent from Checkfront's HTML editor as a booking notification to gmail, my "justify-content" styling is stripped away.

```
 <tr id="5imagesSection" class="ordenTable" style="display: flex; justify-content: center !important;">
<td id="smileyImage1"><a href="https://mymarbellaweekender.com/product-category/boats-and-yachts/"><img src="https://mymarbellaweekender.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/Circle1300.png" height="100" width="100" alt="My Marbella Weekender" data-image="dhvrprieupdm"></a></td>
<td id="smileyImage2" style="margin-top:10%;"><a href="https://mymarbellaweekender.com/product/shuttle-transfers/"><img src="https://mymarbellaweekender.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/Circle2300.png" height="100" width="100" alt="My Marbella Weekender" data-image="un1eob2gwjf1"></a></td>
<td id="smileyImage3" style="margin-top:20%"><a href="https://mymarbellaweekender.com/product-category/beach-pool-clubs/"><img src="https://mymarbellaweekender.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/Circle3300.png" height="100" width="100" alt="My Marbella Weekender" data-image="veaowxr4ebv6"></a></td>
<td id="smileyImage4" style="margin-top:10%;"><a href="https://mymarbellaweekender.com/product/decor-balloons/"><img src="https://mymarbellaweekender.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/Circle4300.png" height="100" width="100" alt="My Marbella Weekender" data-image="oxyhrbhzvjhi"></a></td>
<td id="smileyImage5"><a href="https://mymarbellaweekender.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Catering-Menus-2022.pdf"><img src="https://mymarbellaweekender.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/Circle5300.png" height="100" width="100" alt="My Marbella Weekender" data-image="uy3cf06q540k"></a></td></tr>
```

[Image of HTML not being justified to center and justify-content:center being 'removed'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5stM5.png)

Here is the code for the whole email:
https://codepen.io/Grabgooglesgoogles/pen/OJOGjYz

I would love feedback in case there is an aspect of the code which doesn't follow best practices and in case these other clients are all making allowances for my lack of knowledge

Can I provide more information? Let me know!
Jack

Edit: I've also now tried [changing the table row and table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6tm4.jpg) to divs, but this hasn't helped either.

Comment: `<tr style="display: flex;">`? That doesn't smell right. See [Using flexbox on a table row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46290006/using-flexbox-on-a-table-row)

Comment: Try using ``align-items: center``.

Comment: @kmoser I've read through and appreciate the difficulties. When using tables and table rows, what is the best html to use to center elements?

Comment: @NajmiehSadatSafarabadi I've tried using align-items: center on the <tr> and it hasn't helped. This is for vertical justification instead of horizontal. It's also a flex rule, which may well be stripped away too. What would be the way to justify table rows horizontally before flex?

Comment: @Grabgooglesgoogles It looks like you're using `<div>` elements and `display: flex` in your CodePen. Does that work when you put it in an HTML email? Please update your question to reflect your latest findings.

Comment: Hey @kmoser! I did add that information as an "edit:" yesterday, although perhaps it didn't make sense. 

"Edit: I've also now tried changing the table row and table data to divs, but this hasn't helped either."

Checkfront HTML tool continues to strip the justify-content: center from the table row. I'd love some more ideas if anybody has them! :)

Comment: If you changed the table row and table data to divs, what do you mean by _"Checkfront HTML tool continues to strip the justify-content: center from the table row"_? How can this be, if you changed the table rows to divs?

Comment: @kmoser I mean that despite putting it into Checkfront's HTML notification tool, when the email comes through on gmail the 'style' justify_content has been removed from the code. I wonder whether I'm using it incorrectly but I don't think so. I sent a video to Checkfront to ask but they don't respond:
https://www.loom.com/share/bbf9058481c24adc96241b5b9fce9633

Comment: @Grabgooglesgoogles Have you tried something old-school like `text-align: center;`?

Comment: Hi @kmoser, I've tried text-align: center and it doesn't get removed (probably because it's older and therefore works), but it's not the right styling to center the divs like justify-content: center; does. What would be the old-fashioned way to correctly align tds in a table row? I thought this was with margin: auto, and that's not working for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force each `<td>` to `width: 20%`, otherwise it is only as wide as its contents.

Comment: This solved my issue, thanks @kmoser!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with `margin: auto` in your tr container?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Filippo! I'm afraid that, although margin: auto doesn't get stripped away, it doesn't lead to my elements being centred :/ Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you have to force each `<td>` to be `width: 20%`, and/or set the table's width to 100%?

Comment: @kmoser this has worked!   A massive thank you as this has been worrying me for a week. FYI, the tr width:100%; wasn't necessary, it only needed the width:20%; on each td. Also for what it's worth, if I remove the display: flex; from the table row it doesn't display correctly either.

If you'd like to make an official answer to the question I'd love to upvote it and mark it as the solution. Thanks again! 